# Chromium stopped working

Tags: chromium

When I open Chromium the tabs do not load (even the New Tabs). First, I tried to remove (actually, rename) `~/.config/chromium` to chromium_old and nothing got better. Then I purged and removed all chromium-browser vestige in my laptop. I reinstalled Chromium and tabs are still not working (included Bookmarks, about: ,etc.) 
I can surf the web without any problem in Opera Midori and Firefox.

I am using 10.0.614.0 (69504) Ubuntu 10.10, the problem started yesterday by the night (UTC) when I updated as everyday my chromium-browser packages. Since the problem started I'd updated only once my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was an old libpdf.so that I ported from Chrome a few weeks ago.

I only had to delete `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpdf.so`

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem and deleting this file helped...